# Why does StepVerifier.verifyComplete() is going into infinite loop when I use Scheduler and the test completes when I remove scheduler?

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-webflux, project-reactor, powermockito

I am trying to test orchestrator flow which is using Reactor Mono. When I am testing the flow using StepVerifier the test was never finished. If I remove publishOn(myThreadDispatcher) then the test is completing. I tried StepVerifier withVirtualTime but the thread is finishing too early and returning onComplete instead of OnNext. Please let me know if anything needs to be added or corrected.

```
@Component
public class MyOrchestrator {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myThreadDispatcher")
    private Scheduler myThreadDispatcher;

   @Autowired
   private PrepareRequestInvoker prepareRequestInvoker;


   @Autowired
   private EventHandler eventHandler;



    @Override
    public Mono<Result> orchestrate(FooRequest fooRequest) {
        return Mono.just(fooRequest)
                .publishOn(myThreadDispatcher)
                .flatMap(fooRequest -> prepareRequestInvoker.invoke(fooRequest))
                .flatMap(queryResult -> eventHandler.orchestrate(mockResult, fooRequest));
    }

}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.crypto.*"})
class MyTest{

    @Mock
    private Scheduler myThreadDispatcher;

    @Mock
    private PrepareRequestInvoker prepareRequestInvoker;


    @Mock
    private EventHandler eventHandler;


        @InjectMocks
        private MyOrchestrator orchestrator;
    
        Result mockResult = Result.from("test");
    
     Mono<Result> resultMono = Mono.fromCompletionStage(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mockResult));
    
    
       @Test
    public void testMono(){
        prepareTest(createRequest());
        Mockito.when(prepareRequestInvoker.invoke(fooRequest)).thenReturn(resultMono);
        Mockito.when(eventHandler.orchestrate(mockResult,fooRequest)).thenReturn(resultMono);
        Mono<Result> monoToVerify= orchestrator.orchestrate(fooRequest);
    
        StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(monoToVerify)
                .expectNext(Result.from("test"))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

Comment: `myThreadDispatcher` is a mock, what do you expect it to do? (except silently nothing)

Comment: How do I pass a real Scheduler and expect result from Mono? Mono is emiting expected object in realtime. It is not working in test.

Comment: @xerx593 Basically I want to return a Mocked Mono object when Mono.publishOn to avoid executing tasks on real publisher.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using @Spy and injecting real object in place of mock scheduler. Thanks @xerx593 for throwing some light.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).